# How to use "and" after a complex sentence

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I am a rookie in learning English. I want the clause after "and" to be governed by the same subject, but the sentence before "and" is sometimes complex.

e.g.,

The process reclines to random move where almost all solutions generated from the neighborhood is accepted **AND** reaches global optimum very slowly.

So I want the sentence after AND to inherit **the process** as the subject (so the process reaches...), is it a correct way to write like this? How about other possible subject in that sentence, like **the neighborhood**, **all solutions** ? Sometimes it confuses me about which subject the clause after "AND" will use?

Thanks for the BIG HELP!

Comment: The first part of the sentence doesn't make any sense. What is “the process reclines to random move” supposed to mean? _Recline_ means to lean back in your chair… how can a situation do that? “Reaches global optimum” also sounds quite strange (_optimum_ is usually ideal conditions for a plant to grow—does this have anything to do with plants?). If we ignore that, however, and make the sentence at least grammatical by adding an indefinite article before _random move_ and changing _is_ to _are_, then there's no ambiguity with _and_. That part works fine.

Comment: Just change "is accepted" to "are accepted", and then the sentence is fine.

Comment: You should take a look at our sister site, [ell.se], which is specifically for people who are _learning_ English. This site is for the finer and more niggly points of English grammar and usage; questions like this one are more likely to get good answers on [ell.se].

Comment: I'll give you the advice my spouse always gives me when I present a problematic sentence for fixing: "Think Hemingway.  Use short, simple sentences."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, since your own comments were mistaken, I really wonder whether the question would fare better on the other site.  It's techspeak.  "the process reclines to random move" means that it decays to a process characteristic of random moves.  If you don't know the field (as I do not), you have to be prepared to do some interpretation.

Comment: 'Bill fought with Ben and was injured' means Bill was injured. 'Bill fought with Ben, and he was injured' is ambiguous.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, thanks for your comment. However, the problem I have is how does a reader know which subject the sentence after "and" inherit, i.e., ??? reaches global minimum very slowly (??can be the process, neighborhood, all solutions).

Comment: @GregLee Do you have a source for that techspeak? The collocations “process reclines” and “random move” give zero hits apart from this page.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I understand your point, but my situation is that the sentence before "and" is complex, including more than one clauses.

Comment: @lycnbb It cannot be _all solutions_, because that is plural. It also cannot be _the neighbourhood_ because that is not a subject in the first sentence, but the object of a preposition. It can only be _the process_. A verb can only inherit a subject as its subject, no matter how complex the sentence is.

Comment: 'Bill went to help Ben when Ben's dog fell in the lake and got very wet and cold.' is also ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, in your case, how to make the sentence clear? Thanks

Comment: "reclines" and "reaches" are singular-agreeing verbs which both agree with the singular subject "process".  Nothing else makes sense.  And this makes clear that these verbs head verb phrases which are both predicated of the subject "process".  That's what the OP is asking about.  It's not a problem.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, thanks, that is very helpful. you use "plural' or "singular" to pin down the subject to _process_, however, if all solutions become _the solution_, how can we know which is the subject or how do we write the sentence correctly in the same time we can choose the subject (process or solution) as we wish( I mean, there must be two ways to write the sentence, process is the subject in one way and solution is the subject in the other way).

Comment: 'When Ben's dog fell in the lake (and got very wet and cold), Bill went to help [Ben get him out]. // 'Bill, going to Ben's assistance when Ben's dog fell in the lake, got very wet and cold.'

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, No, I don't have a reference for this "techspeak".  I do have many years' experience editing and correcting technical papers, as well as reading outside my field.  It seems to me that you don't appreciate the part that creativity plays in language understanding.  When you run up against a new term or a word used in a way you're not familiar with, you don't necessarily run to a dictionary, or Google search, you assume provisionally some sense that fits the context and move on.  This is just they way human language works, since even before Google.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you are a genius! Also, in your original sentence, if I put Ben after "and", is it also grammatically correct ? // Bill went to help Ben when Ben's dog fell in the lake and **Ben** got very wet and cold

Comment: It's grammatical, but I wouldn't use it unless you mean 'When Ben's dog fell in the lake and Ben got very wet, Bill went to help him (Ben).' The 'and' really implies a consequence, and one would hope that Bill's helping didn't contribute to Ben's getting soaked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting the example sentence as:

> The process falls back on a move randomly chosen from among all the acceptable solutions generated from the neighborhood and reaches global optimum very slowly.

might explain why "reclines" was used in the posted example. However "reclines" does not share the idiomatic usage of "fall back on" and needs to be replaced. Possible alternatives to "recline" include

- **fall back on** meaning "to begin to use someone or something held in reserve"  [The Free Dictionary, 2.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+back+on),
- **default to** meaning to choose an option when no information is available to make a more specific choice, [TFD, noun, 4.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/default) used as a verb, or
- **degenerate to** to mean decline in function from an original state ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/degenerate)).

In the rewritten example above, "process" is the only noun or noun phrase in the sentence with [nominative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_case). "Move", "all the solutions" and "neighborhood" appear as indirect objects of a preceding verb or past participle and have [dative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case). Dative case is not used for the subject of a verb, leaving "process" as the subject of "reaches".

The original example sentence posted requires slightly different analysis. "When" introduces a [subordinate clause](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm) containing "is" as the verb (which should be "are" to match with "solutions"). Subordinate clauses can take a trailing comma to indicate their status, so inserting a comma after "neighborhood" should clarify that "when ... neighborhood" is a subordinate clause and not the subject of "reaches".

Comment: That is a great lesson!